# Mod_wsgi issue - LoadModule not allowed here

Tags: python, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I want to test mod_wsgi on my server - Ubuntu Server.
My .htaccess:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/apps/hello.py
```

My hello.py:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Apache returns:

> .htaccess: LoadModule not allowed here

My apache conf (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess is in /var/www/sub/
What's wrong with that?

Comment: Can you do that from within `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1):

from Apache doc:

```
Description:    Links in the object file or library, and adds to the list of active modules
Syntax: LoadModule module filename
Context:    server config
Status: Extension
Module: mod_so
```

because its context is `Server config`, So you can not use it in `.htaccess`.

Comment: so, i need to do it all in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default?

Comment: put that in `etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (Apache main config file)

Comment: IOW, also must be outside of any VirtualHost as well. Linux Apache distros generally have a directory called mods-available which contains a file for each module type and LoadModule would be in that. Look at the documentation for your distro.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton you're right, I forgot that, it's better idea.